# Regarding Blender's "Mesh to Volume" geometry node, is there a workaround for using density as an input like the volume cube?

Tags: geometry-nodes, displacement, volumetrics

For reference, I'm looking for an effect similar to Lee Griggs's work using Arnold but through blender's geometry node volume displacement tools. A good example would be their piece *bifrost tim*:

https://www.artstation.com/artwork/3dkeWA

[image]

One of the best methods I've found to replicate this effect allows you to both mix node-based textures *and* convert the displaced volume to mesh through geometry node's new volume to mesh node. However, it seems as though this can only be done using a volume cube as the starting volume versus an original object.

For example, here is a node setup more or less illustrating what I mean:

[image]
[image]

Are there any known workarounds from this limitation? Addons, scripts, node-ing magic, or alternative ways of volumetrically displacing meshes that can be converted back to geometry (for uses like sculpting and 3D printing)? Ideally, the more control over the displacement the better. Proximity displacement and texture mixing are crucial features here.

It would also be really helpful to understand why geometry node's mesh to volume can't use density inputs as well.

Thanks!